# statusBarOrientation returns (Enum Value)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

`println(\(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation))`

prints (Enum Value) to the console. Can I print a meaningful version of the statusBarOrientation property without resorting to

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation == .Portrait
```

etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add extension that conforms `UIInterfaceOrientation` to `Printable` protocol.

```
extension UIInterfaceOrientation: Printable {
    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case Unknown:
            return "Unknown"
        case Portrait:
            return "Portrait"
        case PortraitUpsideDown:
            return "PortraitUpsideDown"
        case LandscapeLeft:
            return "LandscapeLeft"
        case LandscapeRight:
            return "LandscapeRight"
            }
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
println(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation)
```